# Wait for RxJS operation - to blocking?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular 4.3.5.  Our app has "programs" that a user can be "subscribed" to. I have a router guard function that looks like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const programName = route.params['program_name'];
    const programId = this.programService.getIdForName(programName);
    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()  &&  this.subscriptionService.isSubscribed(programId)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return false;
    }
}
```

To get the program id, I need to call the server.  To get the list of subscriptions for the user and determine if they are subscribed to this particular program, I need to call the server.

The server calls are asynchronous using RxJS.  However, my `canActivate` function is constrained to return a boolean.  I am unsure of how to bridge this async/sync programming gap.

In RxJava, for example, I could call `toBlocking()` to wait for the HTTP call to resolve.  But there is no such operator in RxJS.  I've tried `toArray()`, and `take(1).toArray()[0]`, but nothing seems to work.

In fact, I'd like to push this async/sync bridge down lower; i.e. I want `subscriptionService.isSubscribed(programId)` to return a `boolean` instead of a `Observable<boolean>`, because I can cache the list of subscriptions in the `SubscriptionService`, so that I don't need to call the server every time; but I don't think that changes the programming challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canActivate` function can return an `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: Ha, so Observables all the way up?  So be it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thin as blocking in JS.

Angular can handle a returned observable

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const programName = route.params['program_name'];
    return this.programService.getIdForName(programName).map(pn => {
      if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()  &&  this.subscriptionService.isSubscribed(programId)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
        return false;
      }
   });
}
```